# Corrupted index on elasticsearch after the network connectivity issue with AWS

Tags: elasticsearch

We have 3 nodes ES cluster and that has been hosted on AWS. We can see below error message, after the amazon network connectivity issue( see https://status.aws.amazon.com/) which is happen on today. Could you please advise how I can bring up the cluster again to good state, without any data?

[index.store ] [ [.marvel-2015.03.19][0] Failed to open / find files while reading metadata snapshot
[2017-02-10 01:54:54,379][WARN ][index.engine.internal ] [.marvel-2015.03.16][0] failed engine [corrupted preexisting index]
org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: [.marvel-2015.03.16][0] Preexisting corrupted index [corrupted_Jja1GRiPTFyzm4G_tuEvsg] caused by: CorruptIndexException[codec footer mismatch: actua
l footer=1431655765 vs expected footer=-1071082520 (resource: NIOFSIndexInput(path="/es-data//nodes/0/indices/.marvel-2015.03.16/0/index/_83k_es090_0.doc"))]

Answer (score 0):

I would say, compare the data nodes on each node. Try to identify the node with anomaly which may be in the form of file entries with corruptted??? flag or higher data node folder size than the other nodes. If you are lucky then you would have a balanced cluster and other nodes would have full index in the form of primary and replica shards. In such a scenario you can then delete the data folder of the node with anomaly and restart the cluster which then will balance itself again.